# Is the equivalence principle in General Relativity an approximation?

Tags: general-relativity, equivalence-principle, tidal-effect

I read in web that Einstein used the [principle of equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) to explain  General Relativity but we know the gravitation is approximately equal in all of rested frame in gravitional field. In contrary, we can only create uniform acceleration inside a frame if we move it in a direction (The same $a$ will be gotten  in each point of the frame  ) .

Is it possible to create exact equivalence between accelerated frame and rested frame in gravitational field?

How can the general relativity explain the difference?

Comment: It is exact, but holds for *infinitesimal* 'chunks' of spacetime only. Because of the curved nature of spacetime, many intuitive notions only hold infinitesimally, where we can approximate the manifold as flat spacetime.